# How to customize Pull-To-Refresh indicator style in NativeScript/Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I am trying to customize the style of Pull-To-Refresh indicator in NativeScript/Vue app. There seems to be no example code for Vue. I tried to place the following code adapted from Angular into , got errors when running the app.

```
<RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>
    <PullToRefreshStyle indicatorColor="white" indicatorBackgroundColor="blue"/>
</RadListView.pullToRefreshStyle>
```

Can anybody offer a working example or update the following page?
https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/pull-to-refresh

On a side note, according to doc here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-ui-api-reference/classes/pulltorefreshstyle

Only color and background color can be customized. Is there anyway to get around this change size of indicator?

The only way I can think of is to set both foreground and background of indicator to transparent then use page level activityIndicator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the attributes on `pullToRefreshStyle` property

**HTML**

```
<RadListView :pullToRefreshStyle="pullToRefreshStyle">
```

**Script**

```
import * as colorModule from "tns-core-modules/color";

data() {
        return {
            pullToRefreshStyle: {
                indicatorColor: new colorModule.Color("red"),
                indicatorBackgroundColor: new colorModule.Color("green")
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: this works. Is there a way to turn off the pullToRefreshIndicator completely? I tried to set both background and foreground color to "#ffffff", but I still have an empty circle.

Comment: I don't think so, that's not supported by the plugin.

Comment: I guess we will have to wait until when plugin support customization of size and location etc.
Could you update the example code page?